# How do I get the already existing constraints in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

When I've created some constraints on the graph, how is possible to see them and in case eliminate them? What is the syntax to treat them as elements of the graph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the neo4j browser you can use the `:schema` command to list them. 
In shell it is `schema`

Then you can remove them with

```
`DROP INDEX ON :Label(prop)`
```

or

```
`DROP CONSTRAINT ON (n:Label) ASSERT n.props IS UNIQUE`
```

Answer (score 7):

to do this in cypher you can execute

```
CALL db.constraints;
```

which gives a table of constraints from which you can delete entries by referencing the `name` column when executing

```
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Answer (score 6):

In Browser you can use 
**CALL db.constraints** to get all constraints on graph.

For more Info: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for the reply, but this topic is 4 years old ;)

Comment: You can also use this command programmatically - just tested in the neo4j python driver which is 'officially supported' - assuming that means it is a standard driver feature. 4 years old questions need love too ;)

Answer (score 5):

In Neo4j 5.x.x, its `SHOW CONSTRAINT` command.

Answer (score 2):

`SHOW CONSTRAINTS`

I was able to get existing constraints with the above using the [neo4j:5-community](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/neo4j/community/images/sha256-acad44c4c0ce675745008de8cc5b83ecbe88545d3298bfaac0bfe6504ee16381?context=explore) Docker image.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
call db.schemaStatements()
```

seems to give the constraints along with the syntax of the DROP statement as well, ready to copy/paste, for example:

```
DROP CONSTRAINT `publisher_id`
```

Comment: Note that I'm running 4.1.5 Community, which is rather newer than the OP's version! I'm answering here because this information would have been useful to me when I found this answer.