# How can I check the existing CONSTRAINT in neo4j before drop or before re-create the constraint

Tags: neo4j

How can I check the existing CONSTRAINTS in neo4j.

For example I have created one constraint like

**CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (m:BBG_Security_DATA) ASSERT m.ISIN IS UNIQUE;**

Before re-create the same constraint I have to re-check.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Shafeeque

Comment: Or before drop the constraint I have to check that constraint exist or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the already existing constraints in Neo4j?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658285/how-do-i-get-the-already-existing-constraints-in-neo4j)

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j does not complain if you CREATE the same constraint multiple times - returns `(no changes, no records)` in the browser.

It does complain if you try to DROP a constraint that does not exist. As noted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52100849/1089228) (from comment above), you can use:

```
CALL db.constraints
```

to get a current list constraints and decide which need to be dropped.

```
 ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"description"                                                         │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"CONSTRAINT ON ( c:Classification ) ASSERT c.id IS UNIQUE"            │                                            
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"CONSTRAINT ON ( d:Directory ) ASSERT d.id IS UNIQUE"                 │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"CONSTRAINT ON ( f:File ) ASSERT f.id IS UNIQUE"                      │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"CONSTRAINT ON ( p:Perspective ) ASSERT p.id IS UNIQUE"               │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: As of Neo4j 4, creating a constraint seems to throw Neo.ClientError.Schema.EquivalentSchemaRuleAlreadyExists

Comment: Updated for Neo4j 5:

`CREATE CONSTRAINT n10s_unique_uri IF NOT EXISTS FOR (r:Resource) REQUIRE r.uri IS UNIQUE;`